# How can I 'fetchXml' records according to date but not time in CRM?

Tags: javascript, datetime, crm, onchange, fetchxml

I'm dealing with two entities, Appointments and Expenses. My goal is for a new Expense record to auto populate some its fields when the date of the expense is specified, onChange. It triggers a query that's supposed to return records that have the same date and owning user.

Here is my code:

```
function bringData()
{
    var date = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_tripDate").getValue();
    var owner = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ownerid").getValue();
    if (owner != null)
        {
            var ownerID = owner[0].id;
            var ownerName = owner[0].name;    
        }

    var fetchXml="<fetch mapping='logical'>"+"<entity name='appointment'>"+"<attribute name='regardingobjectid'/>"+"<filter>"+"<condition attribute = 'ownerid' operator='eq' value='"+ownerID+"' />"+"<condition attribute='scheduledstart' operator='on' value='"+date+"' />"+"</filter>"+"</entity>"+"</fetch>";
    var retrievedAppointments = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch(fetchXml);
    if (retrievedAppointments.length == 0)
        {
            alert("No matching records were found.");
            return;
        }
    else
        {
            console.log(retrievedAppointments);
        } 
}
```

It gets the date from the current Expense page and uses it for the query. However, the function gives me an error on change saying that the date "is invalid, or outside the supported range". I removed the date condition from the query and it returns records based on the owning user no problem. I figured the problem was that there is a specified time in the Appointment entity and not on the Expense date but I thought using the "on" condition operator would fix that issue. I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: What value is returned by `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_tripDate").getValue()`?

Comment: "new_tripDate" returns the date of the expense. It is a Date Only field so it returns time as 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date time format returned by Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_tripDate").getValue() is something that fetch cannot handle, you need to convert it to an [ISO Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff925953(v=vs.94).aspx) at the bare minimum.

Change the date formatting by using ISOFormat method, or use a library like moment.js or come up with your own little helper function to return a properly formatted date string.
Replace your date variable with the following:

```
var date = new Date(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_tripDate").getValue()).toISOString();
```